# Parse.com - Parsing the value of a long instead of the name/title

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, rest

I'm attempting to send the value of a long (in this case the long mStartTX) however each time I attempt to do so the title/name of the long (mStartTX) appears in my data browser instead of the data the long represents (total bytes of data used since the app launched)

How can this be corrected so the value the long represents appears in parse.com? I'm sure this is very simple. I simply cannot seem to send the data I need using the method below:

```
   testObject.put("time", Long.valueOf(mStartTX));
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
TextView textSsid, textSpeed, textRssi;

public Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public long mStartRX = 0;
public long mStartTX = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.parser);
textSsid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ssid);
textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Speed);
textRssi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rssi);
Long.toString(mStartTX);
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("time", Long.valueOf(mStartTX));
testObject.saveInBackground();


mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED)     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
alert.show();
} else {
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
}
}
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no wonder, `"mStartTX"` is a `String` literal, and `mStartTX` is a variable of type `long`. Use `mStartTX` without quotes, and in case the method doesn't accept long as a parameter, use `Long.toString(mStartTX)` and then parse it using `Long.valueOf(mStartTXStr)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated source using your suggested method - still no data appearing in parse.com

Comment: @JohnCrowley, The issue persists? I mean, the label still appears as "mStartTX" instead of a long value?

Comment: @JohnCrowley, Did you try to debug the code to see what exactly happens?

Comment: I figured it out... I simply had to implement String.valueOf